# How do i access a file that is loaded after?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is in Flash Action Script 3
Here is my class, I loaded an xml in the class
and now i want to do some things after in the main page, like create things on the stage based off of the xml. Help

I understand why it doesn't work, by the time the function is called the xml hasn't be loaded yet, i'm just clueless how to solve this? add an event listener maybe?

```
package  {  
    public class LoadXMLAdventure {
        var adventureXML: XML;
        var xmlReq:URLRequest;
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var _currentRoom:int;

        public function LoadXMLAdventure(xmlFileName:String) {
            xmlReq = new URLRequest(xmlFileName);
            xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
        }

        function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
            adventureXML = new XML(xmlLoader.data)  
            //trace(    adventureXML.toXMLString()  )
        }

        public function myFunction():void{
            trace(adventureXML.toXMLString()) //this does not work
        }
    }

}
```

On my main page

```
var game:LoadXMLAdventure = new LoadXMLAdventure("file.xml");
game.myFunction();
```

**Update**

I want to call a function on the main page so i can do some stage manipulation
this is in the class, i get an error undefined method

```
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
            adventureXML = new XML(xmlLoader.data)  
            this.dispatchEvent( new Event("showRoom") );
}
```

this is on the stage

```
stage.addEventListener("showRoom",showRoom);
function showRoom(e:Event):void{
  trace("showroom hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch an event when the  xml loaded complete,but in your case, you just need to call myFunction in xmlLoaded;

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

public class LoadXMLAdventure extends EventDispatcher{

    public function LoadXMLAdventure(xmlFileName:String) {
        xmlReq = new URLRequest(xmlFileName);
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    }

    public function startLoad():void {
        xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);
    }

    function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
        adventureXML = new XML(xmlLoader.data);

        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("LoadXmlComplete"));
    }
}
```

Here is how to use

```
var game:LoadXMLAdventure = new LoadXMLAdventure("file.xml"); 
game.addEventListener("LoadXmlComplete", onComplete);
game.startLoad();

private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
   //do some thing
}
```

Comment: I got an error on this.dispatchEvent as an undefined method, do i need to include something?

Comment: Yes, you should import  flash.events.EventDispatcher

Comment: i got it, i had to create a _dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();